# When were headshots possible in the series?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-series

I play *The Elder Scrolls: Tamriel Unlimited* a lot and in the forums there has been a (ridiculous) demand of enabling locational damage for bows.

As this is not possible, because in that MMO the character always auto-aims at the chest, I asked myself:

**In which games of *The Elder Scrolls* series were Headshots possible?**

I've spent my whole youth in Morrowind, walked through Cyrodiil and have slain dragons across Skyrim. Though I was never used to a bow - sure, I tested them to see how physics are working and how they implemented it, but I mostly sticked to a "Mage blade" character.

And now I'm curious: Have there been games in the series that used locational damage? Like less damage on the toes, but more on the head.

Comment: In elder scrolls unlimited, you can, in fact, aim manually. Auto aim is there as an aid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has never been possible (vanilla). However, there are quite a few mods which achieve this, in Skyrim and Oblivion.

*Interesting fact : Fallout 3 and New Vegas are using nearly the same engine as Oblivion, and they do localize damage.*

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking about Bethesta's other games and I liked that feature. And I knew of Oblivion mods. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Im calling this out. In oblivion I would guarantee instant kills with a headshot but do half the damage for a body shot on the same enemy

Comment: @Timelord64 : that would be a mod. Only sneak attacks have increased damage. I'm definitely checking this today, though. Just wait till I find the CD !

Comment: Maybe I was just scoring extra crit damage by luck? I never used mods. Though they would have had to set up localised damage for fallout regardless for VATS to work

Comment: @Timelord64 Well, in Oblivion I always aim for the head anyway.